# Reading the mail content of an mbox file using python mailbox

Tags: python, email, mbox

I am trying to print the content of the mail ( Mail body) using Python mailbox.

```
import mailbox

mbox = mailbox.mbox('Inbox')
i=1
for message in mbox:
    print i
    print "from   :",message['from']
    print "subject:",message['subject']
    print "message:",message['**messages**']
    print "**************************************" 
    i+=1
```

But I feel message['**messages**'] is not the right one to print the mail content here. I could not understand it from the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/mailbox.html)

Comment: It is clearer to use: `for i, message in enumerate(mbox):`, you could remove then `i=1` and `i+=1`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

To get the message content, you want to use [`get_payload()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/email.message.html#email.message.Message.get_payload). [`mailbox.Message`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/mailbox.html#mailbox.Message) is a subclass of [`email.message.Message`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/email.message.html#email.message.Message). You'll also want to check [`is_multipart()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/email.message.html#email.message.Message.is_multipart) because that will affect the return value of `get_payload()`. Example:

```
if message.is_multipart():
    content = ''.join(part.get_payload(decode=True) for part in message.get_payload())
else:
    content = message.get_payload(decode=True)
```

Comment: @ cpburnz So it is something like http://pastebin.com/AcYvDQM9  But it did not work. :(

Comment: @LukasGraf It didnt print the message body

Comment: @Sidnext2none You need to `print content` because you're storing the message content in `content`.

Comment: @cpburnz   Aah...Such a silly mistake I made. Problem solved. Thank you.

Comment: @AllWorkersAreEssential I get the error "TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, bytes found" while i try to print(content)

Comment: @Salih You can just put it as `content = ''.join(str(part.get_payload(decode=True)) for part in message.get_payload())` and make it be a string. Not sure what that might cause as far as decoding goes but it will get rid of that error.

Answer (score 19):

```
def getbody(message): #getting plain text 'email body'
    body = None
    if message.is_multipart():
        for part in message.walk():
            if part.is_multipart():
                for subpart in part.walk():
                    if subpart.get_content_type() == 'text/plain':
                        body = subpart.get_payload(decode=True)
            elif part.get_content_type() == 'text/plain':
                body = part.get_payload(decode=True)
    elif message.get_content_type() == 'text/plain':
        body = message.get_payload(decode=True)
    return body
```

this function can give you message body if the body is plain text.

Comment: How do I add support for 'multipart/alternative' ?

Comment: You can replace content_type,