# Message instance has no attribute 'is_multipart'

Tags: python, email, attributeerror

I am trying to write a script that gets me the contents of all the Mails in `~/Maildir`. So I basically copypasted code from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26567942/1329744). Here is the full content of `mailbox.py`:

```
import mailbox
maildir = mailbox.Maildir("~/Maildir");
for message in maildir:
    print message["subject"]
    if message.is_multipart():
        print "ok"
```

It does print the subject of the first message, but instead of printing "ok" then, it dies stating

```
AttributeError: Message instance has no attribute 'is_multipart'
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: could you give an example of a file in `~/MailDir`?

Comment: [`is_multipart()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/email.message.html#email.message.Message.is_multipart) is a method of [`email.message.Message`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/email.message.html#email.message.Message) so you need a `email.message.Message` object to apply it to. What's the type of  `message`?

Comment: @user2314737: presumably this is the [`mailbox` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/mailbox.html) in the stdlib, so [this class](https://docs.python.org/3/library/mailbox.html#mailbox.Message), a subclass of `email.message.Message`..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have forgotten to name your Python version so let me guess — it's Python 2.7, right? In Python 2.7 `mailbox.Maildir` by default [returns](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Lib/mailbox.py#L247) instances of [rfc822.Messages](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Lib/rfc822.py), not `email.Message`s; `rfc822.Message` has a completely different [API](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/rfc822.html).

If you want `mailbox.Maildir` to return `email.Message`s remove default `factory`:

```
maildir = mailbox.Maildir("~/Maildir", factory=None)
```

In Python 3 `rfc822.Message` was removed so `mailbox.Maildir` returns `email.Message`s by default.

Comment: You got it. when I run it using `python3 mailbox.py` it works as expected. Thx for pointing me to it.