# non-recursive walk of email message from mailbox message

Tags: python, python-3.x, mbox

I'm trying to work with email messages in Python 3.7 and struggling with what looks like compatibility issues.  The docs mention `email.message.Message` having an `iter_parts` method that should allow me to do a non-recursive walk of message parts.

This doesn't exist on messages returned from `mailbox` messages and it's taken me a while to get it behaving.  For example, I can generate a dummy message with:

```
from email.message import EmailMessage

msg = EmailMessage()
msg['Subject'] = 'msg 1'
msg.add_alternative("Plain text body", subtype='plain')
msg.add_alternative("<html><body><p>HTML body</p></body></html>", subtype='html')
msg.add_attachment(b"Nothing to see here!", maintype='data', subtype='raw')
```

and then dump out the parts with:

```
def iter_parts(msg):
  ret = msg.get_content_type()
  if msg.is_multipart():
    parts = ', '.join(iter_parts(m) for m in msg.iter_parts())
    ret = f'{ret} [{parts}]'
  return ret

iter_parts(msg)
```

which gives me: `multipart/mixed [multipart/alternative [text/plain, text/plain], data/raw]`

but if I save this to a mbox file and reload it:

```
import mailbox
mbox = mailbox.mbox('/tmp/test.eml')
mbox.add(msg)
iter_parts(mbox[0])
```

it tells me `AttributeError: 'mboxMessage' object has no attribute 'iter_parts'`

Initially I thought it might be related to https://stackoverflow.com/a/45804980/1358308 but setting `factory=None` doesn't seem to do much in Python 3.7.

Am posting my solution, but would like to know if there are better options!

Answer (score 1):

After much poking and reading of source I found that I can instead do:

```
from email import policy
from email.parser import BytesParser

mbox = mailbox.mbox('/tmp/test.eml', factory=BytesParser(policy=policy.default).parse)
```

and then I get objects with an `iter_parts` method.